# Am I doing the first time experience with ssh-copy-id right?

Tags: ssh, password, openssh

Every time I want to get someone access to a machine, I ask them to do a ssh-copy-id. I do this after I create a user account on the machine and a random password. This often happens via email.

Between the period of asking the person to do a ssh-copy-id and them acting on it (which can take some hours to days), I have to keep my machine open to password login “`PasswordAuthentication yes`”.

Is there a way to make this workflow better? I don’t want to expose sshd to password login and often between the conversation I end up forgetting to set `PasswordAuthentication no`.

Comment: You can ask this person to send you her *public* key by email and add it to  ``authorized_keys`` manually. Note that public key is not secret.

Comment: Further to @user996142's comment, you can ask them to send it by email _as an attachment_ to reduce the number of keys that need to be massaged because of mail formatting.

Comment: @user996142 For that i should create a .ssh folder, touch authorized_keys, set perms etc. right? i want to avoid that. Is there a generic authorize_keys file for all users?

Comment: How could it be generice ``authorize_keys``? How  OpenSSH should map public key to user?

Answer (score 1):

1. Ask them to generate the key by themselves. Sending passwords or private keys over the email is never a good idea. Even though the transport should be secure, the mails are lying for years on at least two servers that might not be trusted (freemails, ...).
2. Exposing password authentication just of this use case is not worth it. You can simply forget to get it back, or restart the service and you end up with password authentication opened. If you have to, just enable it for this single user:

   ```
   Match user new-user
     PasswordAuthentication yes
   ```
3. Create a script that will set the public key and correct permissions for a new user. It is either few lines directly on that server, or even you can use the `ssh-copy-id` with `-f` switch (if you already enable password auth) to minimize the window of opening your server.
4. If you want to have a control of the public keys used for authentication and avoid users writing/modifying their authorized keys, you can configure the `AuthorizedKeysFile` to some common directory, where you will have a control of the access, for example

   ```
   AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/authorized_keys/%u
   ```

   This will search for the file for a user `new-user` in `/etc/ssh/authorized_keys/new_user`. The files created in the directory under `/etc/` should have default permissions suitable for ssh.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the way Hetzner Online (a German ISP) does it at least with their Linux VPSes when setting up for public key authentication (which they offer as a choice during provisioning, as an alternative to setting a password for the `root` account).

**Ask the user to submit a public key *before* you allow them to access their account.** Don't ever set a password for the user account yourself, and if you want to, keep everything but `PubkeyAuthentication` turned off all the time in your sshd. Insert the key provided by the user into the user's own ~/.ssh/authorized_keys as soon as you create their account, or immediately after you receive it but before they are allowed access. Assuming OpenSSH, you could even set up your SSH server to accept password authentication only from localhost (using a `Match` stanza in /etc/ssh/sshd_config), which should allow you to use the `ssh-copy-id` workflow locally, ensuring that things like permissions and ownership are set correctly.

**This way, the user retains full control over their private key at all times, and no data that won't be shared anyway gets transmitted. You also don't train them to accept someone else generating the private key.** Amazon might be able to get it right -- I'd have my doubts, personally, and would certainly want to replace the key pair immediately -- but what are the odds that you can invest as much into getting that process right as they have?

You should ideally ask for the public key to be transmitted over an encrypted channel, but that's not so much for privacy as it is for *authenticity*. The user wants to be sure that they are communicating with the entity they believe they are communicating with, and you want to be at least reasonably sure that nobody is acting as an active man in the middle and modifying the communications and replacing the public key with their own. **But even sending the public key in plain, unsecured e-mail isn't so bad.** After all, the public key is meant to be public.

If you set up new accounts only rarely, and for people you have an established relationship with, you can even call the user on the phone and ask them to read out their SSH key fingerprint, and verify this against what you received. Give them the fingerprint for the host key(s) at the same time. That way, they too can have assurance that they are connecting to the correct host even the first time. (Hetzner includes the host key fingerprints in the "your VPS is ready" e-mail.)

Answer (score -1):

Do it the Amazon way -- generate a public/private keypair for them, and send them the private key.  They will need to submit that private key to authenticate (`ssh -i /path/to/key.pem user@host`), and this way, you won't ever need to enable SSH password authentication.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the commenters, I finally see where they are coming from.  To *initially share* the private key with the user, it should be sent over a secure channel such as HTTPS.

Comment: I usually do this too. If they want to add their private key, they already have access.

Comment: @Gohu -- It's SSH. It stands for *Secure* SHell.  This is the standard procedure for Amazon Web Services, whose servers run a large portion of the entire Internet. It's not like you're sending the private key in an HTTP request.

Comment: You did not specify how the private key will be shared. To me your answer is lacking a strong warning on that point.

Comment: @Gohu -- I explicitly stated exactly how the private key would be shared -- over SSH -- the `-i` flag tells `ssh` where the private key is located.  `ssh -i /path/to/key.pem user@host` will submit the private key to the remote `sshd` listener on the `host` over the encrypted `ssh` connection, and if it matches the public key in the `user`'s ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file, they will be able to login.

Comment: @rubynorails, Amazon provides the private key to the end user over an https connection, not via secure shell.  Your answer as it currently stands "send them the private key" gives no mention of transferring the private key _securely_.  Not all people needing to provide `ssh` access to machines are necessarily running `https` servers to distribute keys.

Comment: @rubynorails, the question is not how the key is specified on the command line _after_ it is transmitted to the end user.  The problem is the initial transfer.  Further, the `-i` flag does not indicate the location of a private key which will be "submitted" to the remote `sshd` over an encrypted connection.  The asymmetric key authentication handshake does not require the private key to be transmitted at all.

Comment: My apologies; I finally see where you guys are coming from and have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @user4556274 please enlighten me on what the `-i` flag is intended for then. I never said SSH requires you to specify a private key, but the argument of the `-i` parameter does indeed specify the location of one to be used in the exchange.

Comment: @rubynorails, this is getting off topic a bit now.  I agree with the language used in this most recent comment: specify the key "to be used in the exchange", but not the earlier wording "will submit the private key to the remote `sshd`"  It is misleading to use language which suggests that _the private key itself_ is transmitted between client and server during authentication.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of work. As a user this looks like i have to use give private key, then append it, ssh-copy-id my regular public key, delete previous private key etc.

Comment: @QuintinPar, it's only a one-time setup task from the user's perspective (if they opt for using public key authentication over using the private key each time), but it's a gift that keeps on giving from an administrative standpoint.